# Redis Sets - date added

Tags: redis

I currently have a Redis Set and I'm not sure if this is possible but thought I'd ask just in case someone knows of a way around it. Is it possible to add a date of when a new element for a key is created when using 'SADD' command?

I've tried searching the web but I can't find anything, which tells me its not possible. Is there another way of doing this? Something like the below and then being able to get the date the element was created?

SADD my:key:string "1000", Time.now

Comment: You can keep track with a parallel set that saves the date of each insertion, doing for example `SADD my:key:string "the_date"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Sorted Set instead of a Set. Using the timestamp as a score will allow you to retrieve your values ordered by date, values for a given date, values after of before a given date, etc. Or of course just the date for the value.

```
ZADD myzset 12345678 "my value"
```

Comment: This looks like the most sensible approach, using the UNIX time as score. This will also allow to query for ranges of time easily.

Comment: Nice. The thing is I'm already using 'Set' in production. So if I wanted to use this then I'll need to some how transfer them all to a 'Sorted Set'. How would I do that?

Comment: Either you write some applicative code (in PHP, Java, Ruby, Python, whatever), or a LUA script to be executed by Redis. The first solution is better if the volume of data is really big, as the Lua script will block other requests processing during its execution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the date of an element save the element in form of json :

SADD mset "{value:1000,created:18-03-2014}"

So when you retrieve the element its creation date will be also be retrieved.

Comment: This is a good solution. If transferring to a 'Sorted Set' becomes problematic then I think I'll be doing this.